# After adding volumes to docker-compose, changes are not being picked up for frontend files

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

So I have this working as expected with flask where I used...

```
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
```

And any files that I change in the `api` are picked up by the running session. I'd like to do the same for the frontend code.

For node/nginx, I used the below configuration. The only way for the file changes to be picked up is if I rebuild. I'd like for file changes to be picked up as they do for python but a bit stuck on why similar set up is not working for `src` files. Anyone know why this might be happening?

local path structure

```
public\
src\
Dockerfile.client
docker--compose.yml
```

docker file...

```
FROM node:16-alpine as build-step
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json ./
COPY ./src ./src
COPY ./public ./public
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build


FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=build-step /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

docker-compose

```
  client:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.client
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - api
```

Comment: It's not really clear in your question what you have tried besides rebuilding the images. The volume change should be picked up by simply recreating the containers from the existing image (e.g. without rebuilding with a command like `docker-compose up -d --force-recreate`)

Comment: I added some text to be clearer - I want changes that I make locally / hit save to be picked up as it currently does for changes I do to the files in the local `api` folder for flask. I have done the same type of volume mount for `client` with `src` but the file changes are not being picked up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are building the application.

```
...
RUN yarn build
...
```

and them using your build folder:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=build-step /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I believe that what you are looking for is a live reload. You can find a good example [here](https://simplernerd.com/docker-nodemon/).

But basically what you need is a `Dockerfile` like this:

```
# Dockerfile
# Pull official Node.js image from Docker Hub
FROM node:12
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Install dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
# Bundle app source
COPY . .
# Expose container port 3000
EXPOSE 3000
# Run "start" script in package.json
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

your npm start script:

```json
 "start": "nodemon -L server/index.js"
```

and your volume:

```
    volumes:
      - ./api:/usr/src/app/serve
```

Comment: Giving it a shot the reference to nginx - are you saying that needs to change as well or it's fine to leave as is?

Comment: For development only, I don’t think that using nginx is necessary. I just use it for production

Comment: Yeah, I'm just learning as I go based on some repo I was using. I'll keep nginx to production